# ClassNotFoundException in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run my J2EE project. The same project was working before and I started getting this exception now. I am sure that all class are there along with their mapping files.

If I remove mapping of jobtitle from my hibernate.cfg.xml in the project, it is running.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
hrm.dao.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:28)
hrm.dao.AbstractDAO.<init>(AbstractDAO.java:29)
hrm.dao.JobSpecificationDAO.<init>(JobSpecificationDAO.java:22)
hrm.actions.JobSpecificationAction.execute(JobSpecificationAction.java:53)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hrm.dao.Jobtitle
```

Comment: Can you please add some context about what might have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hrm.dao.Jobtitle
```

means you do indicate a mapping in your `hibernate.cfg.xml`, but a mapping to a class which is not in the classpath of the j2ee project.